# RecycleView causing Kivy executable to crash

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

I followed the [directions in the Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html#alternate-installations) on how to package applications for Windows, but my application crashes as soon as I try to run it. The last line of the traceback suggests a problem with my RecycleView widget:

```
   File "C:\Users\awende\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\factory.py", line 139, in __getattr__
     module = __import__(name=item['module'], fromlist='.')
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.uix.recycleview.__init__.'
Failed to execute script SingleTabApp
```

I have tried importing kivy.uix.recycleview in all my .py and .kv files that it wasn't already imported in, but this doesn't seem to be the problem. I am not sure if this is a problem with my code, or if something else is going on.

Other potentially relevant information:

- I am using Python 3.6.1 with the current dev version of PyInstaller.
- Kivy version 1.10.0
- *SingleTabApp* is the name of my main Python script, and was working correctly prior to using PyInstaller.

Comment: I had the same problem and opened an Kivy issue  on github. (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5276) Seems someone has found a solution there (I didn't have time to test so far).

Answer (score 0):

install a recent version of cython, notice that for a version of cython there is a corresponding version of kivy. To implement RecycleView, the version of kivy in your "package apk" not your computer must be at least 1.10

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same problem with `PyInstaller` on `Windows 7`. I appied a quick fix to `factory_registers.py` and it worked! (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5276)

> A quick fix for the issue with pyinstaller is to change e.g. r('RecycleViewBehavior', module='kivy.uix.recycleview.init') to r('RecycleViewBehavior', module='kivy.uix.recycleview').

PS `factory_registers.py` also has `r('RecycleView', module='kivy.uix.recycleview.__init__')`, I didn't touch it.